# Hot to combine the 4 queries to one without sub queries which have multiple conditions?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I want the queries below:

```
Select groupId,count (distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID) as [ChildAddedcurrent] 
from #temp1 Where MonthFlag=0 and ParticipantTypeName='child'
and GroupProgramYearParticipantID not in (Select distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID from #temp1
Where MonthFlag=1 and ParticipantTypeName='child')
group by groupId

Select groupId,count (distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID) as [CaregiverAddedcurrent] 
from #temp1 Where MonthFlag=0 and ParticipantTypeName='caregiver'
and GroupProgramYearParticipantID not in (Select distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID from #temp1
Where MonthFlag=1 and ParticipantTypeName='caregiver')
group by groupId

Select groupId,count (distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID) as [ChildAddedprior] 
from #temp1 Where MonthFlag=1 and ParticipantTypeName='child'
and GroupProgramYearParticipantID not in (Select distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID from #temp1
Where MonthFlag=2 and ParticipantTypeName='child')
group by groupId

Select groupId,count (distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID) as [caregiverAddedPrior] 
from #temp1 Where MonthFlag=1 and ParticipantTypeName='caregiver'
and GroupProgramYearParticipantID not in (Select distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID from #temp1
Where MonthFlag=2 and ParticipantTypeName='caregiver')
group by groupId
```

To be more like this:

```
select groupID,
count(distinct case when MonthFlag=0 and ParticipantTypeName='child' 
and GroupProgramYearParticipantID not in (Select distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID from #temp1
Where MonthFlag=1 and ParticipantTypeName='child') then GroupProgramYearParticipantID end) as [ChildAddedcurrent],
count(distinct case when MonthFlag=0 and ParticipantTypeName='caregiver'
and GroupProgramYearParticipantID not in (Select distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID from #temp1
Where MonthFlag=1 and ParticipantTypeName='caregiver') then GroupProgramYearParticipantID end) as [CaregiverAddedcurrent],
count(distinct case when MonthFlag=1 and ParticipantTypeName='child'
and GroupProgramYearParticipantID not in (Select distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID from #temp1
Where MonthFlag=2 and ParticipantTypeName='child')then GroupProgramYearParticipantID end) as [ChildAddedprior],
count(distinct case when MonthFlag=1 and ParticipantTypeName='caregiver'
and GroupProgramYearParticipantID not in (Select distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID from #temp1
Where MonthFlag=2 and ParticipantTypeName='caregiver') then GroupProgramYearParticipantID end) as [caregiverAddedPrior]
From #temp1
group by groupID
```

But I get an error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: just confirming the expected result. in each query there is a Where filter "and GroupProgramYearParticipantID not in ". the sub query to filter this GroupProgramYearParticipantID does not account for GroupID but Outer Most query is using GroupBY GroupID column. are you sure that when filtering the "GroupProgramYearParticipantID" for IN clause the result should look across all GroupID ?

Comment: It should look for only in corresponding group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaron is right about the parsing error.

Also, the problem with the NOT IN clause means you have to examine ever id to rule out a row.  This is a very very expensive operation when data is large.

Using common table expressions CTEs with SET operators is your key.  See my article on set operators.

http://craftydba.com/?p=5617

First, create CTE's for each month (0, 1, 2) for each category (child, care giver).

```
;
-- Child +0M
with cteChildMonth0
as
(
select groupID as group_id, GroupProgramYearParticipantID as participant_id
from #temp1
where MonthFlag=0 and ParticipantTypeName='child'
),

-- Child +1M
cteChildMonth1
as
(
select groupID as group_id, GroupProgramYearParticipantID as participant_id
from #temp1
where MonthFlag=1 and ParticipantTypeName='child'
),

-- Child +2M
cteChildMonth2
as
(
select groupID as group_id, GroupProgramYearParticipantID as participant_id
from #temp1
where MonthFlag=2 and ParticipantTypeName='child'
),

-- Giver +0M
cteCareGiverMonth0
as
(
select groupID as group_id, GroupProgramYearParticipantID as participant_id
from #temp1
where MonthFlag=0 and ParticipantTypeName='caregiver'
),

-- Giver +1M
cteCareGiverMonth1
as
(
select groupID as group_id, GroupProgramYearParticipantID as participant_id
from #temp1
where MonthFlag=1 and ParticipantTypeName='caregiver'
),

-- Giver +2M
cteCareGiverMonth2
as
(
select groupID as group_id, GroupProgramYearParticipantID as participant_id
from #temp1
where MonthFlag=2 and ParticipantTypeName='caregiver'
),
```

Second, create CTE's for current versus prior using the previous 6 CTE's and SET notation operator EXCEPT.  This is done at the table level, it should be faster than NOT IN.  For each row, create a dummy counter = 1 for the report.

```
-- Child add current
cteChildAddCurrent
(
select group_id, 'Child Current' as category_txt, 1 as participant_cnt
from cteChildMonth0 except cteChildMonth0 
),

-- Child add prior
cteChildAddPrior
(
select group_id, 'Child Prior' as category_txt, 1 as participant_cnt
from cteChildMonth1 except cteChildMonth2
),

-- Giver add current
cteGiverAddCurrent
(
select group_id, 'Giver Current' as category_txt, 1 as participant_cnt
from cteCareGiverMonth0 except cteCareGiverMonth1
),

-- Giver add prior
cteGiverAddPrior
(
select group_id, 'Giver Prior' as category_txt, 1 as participant_cnt
from cteCareGiverMonth1 except cteCareGiverMonth2
),
```

Third, combine the 4 categories into one table.

```
-- Giver add prior
cteSummaryRpt
(
select * from cteChildAddCurrent
union all
select * from cteChildAddPrior
union all
select * from cteGiverAddPrior
union all
select * from cteGiverAddCurrent
)
```

Last but not least, group by id, category text, and participant count.

```
select group_id, category_txt, sum(participant_cnt) as total
from cteSummaryRpt
group by group_id, category_txt
```

I broke down this solution into sections to explain it but in reality it is one big query.  Also, since you did not provide sample tables and/or data, please check the syntax since I did not.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION` (removes duplicates) or `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT x.groupId, x.Count, x.Type FROM
(    
    Select GroupId,
           Count = count(distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID),
           Type  = 'ChildAddedcurrent'
    from #temp1 Where MonthFlag=0 and ParticipantTypeName='child'
    and GroupProgramYearParticipantID not in (Select distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID from #temp1
    Where MonthFlag=1 and ParticipantTypeName='child')
    group by groupId

    UNION ALL

    Select GroupId,
           Count = count(distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID),
           Type  = 'CaregiverAddedcurrent'
    from #temp1 Where MonthFlag=0 and ParticipantTypeName='caregiver'
    and GroupProgramYearParticipantID not in (Select distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID from #temp1
    Where MonthFlag=1 and ParticipantTypeName='caregiver')
    group by groupId

    UNION ALL

    Select GroupId,
           Count = count(distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID),
           Type  = 'ChildAddedprior'
    from #temp1 Where MonthFlag=1 and ParticipantTypeName='child'
    and GroupProgramYearParticipantID not in (Select distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID from #temp1
    Where MonthFlag=2 and ParticipantTypeName='child')
    group by groupId

    UNION ALL

    Select GroupId,
           Count = count(distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID),
           Type  = 'caregiverAddedPrior'
    from #temp1 Where MonthFlag=1 and ParticipantTypeName='caregiver'
    and GroupProgramYearParticipantID not in (Select distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID from #temp1
    Where MonthFlag=2 and ParticipantTypeName='caregiver')
    group by groupId

) X
```

Note that i've added a `Type` column and changed the `count` column with the unique column  name to `Count`. To determine the source of a row i've added the `Type` column.
Now you can even order/filter by one of these columns if desired.

Comment: I want these queries to be in one single query using case statements. Can you please check my question now.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  It certainly won't be more readable and it probably won't perform as well (unless there's a reason).